# What's the best way to provide reusable streams for my Google Visualization API Wrapper?

Tags: events, dart, google-visualization, dart-async, dart-js-interop

I am developing a Dart based wrapper for the [Google Visualization / Charts API](https://developers.google.com/chart/) that can be viewed over at [github](https://github.com/roberthartung/google_visualization_api) already. I created a chart specific wrapper classes for all the charts that are available.

Right now I am looking into the events of the underlying classes. The problem is that there are various events that are **not** shared across all charts. Thus I need to find a way to assign specific event types to their corresponding charts. What I already did is:

1. I created a wrapper for the [Events](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#events) api:

   ```
   abstract class Events {
     static JsObject addListener(source_visualization, event_name, Function handling_function) {
       return vis['events'].callMethod('addListener', [source_visualization, event_name, new JsFunction.withThis(handling_function)]);
     }

     static JsObject addOneTimeListener(source_visualization, event_name, handling_function(e)) {
       return vis['events'].callMethod('addOneTimeListener', [source_visualization, event_name, new JsFunction.withThis(handling_function)]);
     }

     static void removeListener(listener_handler) {
       return vis['events'].callMethod('removeListener', [listener_handler]);
     }

     /// TODO(rh): removeAllListeners
   }
   ```
2. I created a [wrapper class](https://github.com/roberthartung/google_visualization_api/blob/master/lib/src/base/events.dart#L42) that encapsulates all the code for one event The code looks like this:

   ```
   class EventWrapper<E extends Event> {
     JsObject _jsChart;
     String _eventName;
     JsObject _handler;
     Stream<E> get onEvent => _streamController.stream;
     StreamController<E> _streamController;
     ...
     EventWrapper(this._jsChart, this._eventName, E reviver(p)) {
       _streamController = new StreamController.broadcast(onListen: () => _onListen(_eventName), onCancel: () => _onCancel(_eventName));
     }

     void _onListen(String event) {
       _handler = Events.addListener(_jsChart, event, ...);
     }

     void _onCancel(String event) {
       Events.removeListener(_handler);
     }
   }
   ```
3. In the chart you can use the code like this:

   ```
   class PieChart ... {
     Stream<SelectEvent> get onSelect => _selectEventHandler.onEvent;
     EventWrapper _selectEventHandler;

     PieChart(Element e) : super._(e, "PieChart", vis) {
       _selectEventHandler = new EventWrapper<SelectEvent>(jsChart, 'select', (p) => new SelectEvent());
       // Other Events
     }
     // ...
   }
   ```

*The problem is the following*: The `Events` interface requires a `source_visulization` argument, that is the chart I want to register events on. But as I use `dart:js` this is only available AFTER I called the constructor on my chart, because this creates the object via `JsObject`  (`jsChart = new JsObject(ctx[chartName], [element])`). Usually I would create the `EventWrapper` instances within the constructor, but as I have to use the events in several classes I thought of two other solutions than the current on you can see at #3.

1. Create a mixin - this does not really work, because I do not have a constructor and I cannot specify an instsance method because it gives me an error:

   ```
   abstract class SelectEventMixin {
     Stream<SelectEvent> get onSelect => _selectEventHandler.stream;
     final StreamController _selectEventHandler = new StreamController.broadcast(onListen: _onListen);

     void _onListen() {
       // jsChart is available here
     }
   }
   ```
2. Create BaseClasses for each combination of events seen, this would allow me to share the most common code. Some BaseClasses would be: `NoEvents`, `SelectEvent`, `SelectReadyEvents`, `SelectReadyAnimationFinishEvents`, ...

Does anyone of you have a better solution? Or can somebody tell me how to fix my problem #1? Is #2 already the best solution? As I would only have to combine the several methods and only have a little duplicated code?